# How to get user define move constructor called

Tags: c++11, move

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class c
{
    public:
        c(){ cout << "Default ctor" << endl; }
        c(const c& o) { cout << "Copy ctor" << endl; }
        c(c&& o){ cout << "move copy ctor" << endl; }   // Line 11
        //c(c&& o) = delete;                            // Line 12
        ~c() { cout << "Destructor" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    c o = c();                                          // Line 18
    c p = std::move(c());
    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code produces the below output.

```
Default ctor
Default ctor
move copy ctor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

However, if I deactivate line#11 and activate line#12 then it gives below compile time error.

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:18:13: error: use of deleted function 'c::c(c&&)'
   18 |     c o = c();
      |             ^
prog.cc:12:9: note: declared here
   12 |         c(c&& o)=delete;
      |         ^
```

which implies that, line#18 invokes the move copy constructor provided by compiler. How to get my user defined move constructor in line#11 invoked without using `std::move`?

Or `std::move` is the only way to get user defined move constructors invoked?

Comment: Oftentimes we might want to copy your code to try it out ourselves. By having line-numbers you make that a lot harder. Please don't post code with line-numbers. If you want to mark out a specific line then please add comments on it instead.

Comment: Regarding your problem, can you please elaborate? You say that you want `c o = c()` to invoke the move constructor, but according to the error message you show, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand your pain, but since there are multiple references of line numbers in my code, hence added the line numbers so as to make it easy to understand.
I want the move constructor defined by me to be invoked by line#18, which is not the case if you look at the output.

Comment: From the compilers point of view, there's no different between `c o;` and `c o = c();`. So it can simply optimizes `c o = c();` to plain `c o;`. However, if you `delete` the move constructor that's not possible anymore, since the move constructor still have to be considered.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude All I'm asking is `"Why move constructor defined in line#11 doesn't get invoked by line#18 of code?"`

Comment: Please read about [*copy elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: "which implies that, line#18 invokes the move copy constructor provided by compiler" I don't get it, You have deleted the move constructor and provided a copy constructor, the compiler doesn't provide a move constructor in this case. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor